# Is it possible to create a QGIS Windows Installer from my own source on Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, installation

I would like to create a standalone Windows installer for QGIS from the modifications I have made locally to my source in Ubuntu.  I have done various things like change the splash image and added some functionality here and there.  I can build and successfully run this version on Ubuntu.

I am able to use the creatensis.pl script to create a Windows Installer executable...

```
cd <source>/ms-windows/osgeo4w
./creatensis.pl qgis
```

but it seems to use the qgis master version as its source.  When I install the resulting executable on Windows, it shows none of the changes that I made.